# SQL Server ISNULL function not working in derived query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the follow query that has a derived (sub-query) column in it. I am using the `ISNULL` function inside it, however my query output still has null values in it. Why is the `ISNULL` function not working as expected? The rows that you see resulting to `NULL` should actually be outputting as "Test"

```
SELECT 
    PS_PO_HDR.PO_ID,
    PS_PO_HDR.BUSINESS_UNIT,
    (SELECT ISNULL(PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.COMMENTS_2000, 'TEST') 
     FROM PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS  
     WHERE 
         -- PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID='0000000003' AND
         PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT 
         AND PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.PO_ID = PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID 
         AND PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.LINE_NBR = PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR 
         AND PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.COMMENT_TYPE = 'LIN') AS "NOTE_TO_VENDOR",
    'DR' AS 'DISCOUNT_REASON'
FROM 
    PS_PO_LINE PS_PO_LINE, PS_PO_HDR PS_PO_HDR
WHERE 
    PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_PO_HDR.BUSINESS_UNIT
    AND PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID = PS_PO_HDR.PO_ID  
    AND PS_PO_HDR.PO_STATUS NOT IN ('C', 'X', 'PX')
```

Sample results:

```
PO_ID           BUSINESS_UNIT         NOTE_TO_VENDOR        DISCOUNT_REASON
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000004      11MMS                 NULL                  DR
0000000016      41000                 NULL                  DR
0000000021      41000                 Test Note1            DR
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NULL` is being returned by the *subquery* itself, not as a value from a row.  The subquery returns no rows, and that is represented as `NULL`.

There are two options for handling this:

You can either use aggregation in the subquery:

```
(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.COMMENTS_2000), 'TEST') 
. . .
```

The aggregation forces the subquery to return one row.

Or you can move the `ISNULL()` logic outside the subquery:

```
ISNULL( (SELECT PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.COMMENTS_2000
         FROM . . .
        ), 'TEST'
      )
```

Comment: Excellent, the 2nd option worked perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
PS_PO_HDR.PO_ID ,
PS_PO_HDR.BUSINESS_UNIT ,
**ISNULL(**(SELECT ISNULL(PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.COMMENTS_2000, 'TEST') 
  FROM PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS  
  WHERE -- PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID='0000000003' AND
  PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.BUSINESS_UNIT=PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT 
  AND PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.PO_ID=PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID 
  AND PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.LINE_NBR=PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR 
  AND PS_PO_COMMENTS_FS.COMMENT_TYPE='LIN' ), **'TEST')** AS "NOTE_TO_VENDOR"  ,
'DR' AS 'DISCOUNT_REASON'
FROM PS_PO_LINE PS_PO_LINE, PS_PO_HDR PS_PO_HDR
WHERE 
 PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT=PS_PO_HDR.BUSINESS_UNIT
  AND PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID=PS_PO_HDR.PO_ID  
  AND PS_PO_HDR.PO_STATUS NOT IN ('C','X','PX')
```